# Two fragments load upon creation of view in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 tabs in view pager names (Scheduled, InProcess and Finished) as position 0,1,2 respectively. The issue I'm facing now is that when the view is created,  it execute method `loadData()` to load "Scheduled" and "InProcess" data. Then when I swipe to "InProcess" fragment, The "Finished" data loads. But when I swipe to "Finished" fragment nothing happens. Then when I swipe back to "InProcess" fragment It loads "Scheduled" data and so on. What I'm I doing wrong here.

**TabFragment.java**

```
  public static TabFragment newInstance(int position, String name) {
    TabFragment fragment = new TabFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_TAB_POSITION, position);
    args.putString(ARG_TAB_NAME, name);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public TabFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {

        int position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_TAB_POSITION);
        String name = getArguments().getString(ARG_TAB_NAME);
        itemList = new ArrayList<>();

    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view;
    int tabPosition = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt(ARG_TAB_POSITION) : -1;
    String tabName = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString(ARG_TAB_NAME) : "";

    // Inflate the corresponding layout file based on the tab position
    switch (tabPosition) {
        case 0:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_scheduled, container, false);
            recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerViewAdapter = new MeetingListAdapter(context);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
            noDataAnimationView=view.findViewById(R.id.noDataAnimationView);
            loadData();
            break;
        case 1:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_inprocess, container, false);
            recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager2);
            recyclerViewAdapter = new MeetingListAdapter(context);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
            noDataAnimationView=view.findViewById(R.id.noDataAnimationView);
            loadData();
            break;
        case 2:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_finished, container, false);
            recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager3 = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager3);
            recyclerViewAdapter = new MeetingListAdapter(context);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
            noDataAnimationView=view.findViewById(R.id.noDataAnimationView);
            loadData();
            break;
        default:
            // Return an empty view if the tab position is invalid
            return new View(context);
    }
    // Load data if it hasn't been loaded yet
    return view;
}


private void loadData() {
    int tabPosition = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt(ARG_TAB_POSITION) : -1;
    String tabName = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString(ARG_TAB_NAME) : "";
    // Perform the appropriate Volley request based on the tab position
    switch (tabPosition) {
        case 0:
            GET_MEETING_LIST("Scheduled");
            Log.i("KICK", "Tab-Scheduled");
            break;
        case 1:
            GET_MEETING_LIST("InProcess");
            Log.i("KICK", "Tab-InProcess");
            break;
        case 2:
            GET_MEETING_LIST("Finished");
            Log.i("KICK", "Tab-Finished");
            break;
        default:
            // Handle invalid tab position
            break;
    }
}
```

**Activity.java**

```
public class MeetingListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private TabAdapter adapter;
private List<TabFragment> fragmentList;

private static final String ARG_TAB_NAME = "tab_name";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_meeting_list);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    fragmentList.add(TabFragment.newInstance(0, "Scheduled"));
    fragmentList.add(TabFragment.newInstance(1, "InProcess"));
    fragmentList.add(TabFragment.newInstance(2, "Finished"));

    adapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position).getArguments().getString(ARG_TAB_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        // Force fragments to be recreated when the position changes
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Viewpager loads 2 fragments/pages by default. So make it load only one.

```
int offscreenLimit = 1; // Number of pages to retain on either side

viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(offscreenLimit);
```